# Calling function of deployed contract with calldata

Tags: solidity, calldata

Hello I'm trying to call the function `fulfillBasicOrder` of the [Seaport Contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00000000006c3852cbEf3e08E8dF289169EdE581) and I keep getting that it has failed without any further informations. Does someone know what I might do wrong ? This is my function in my contract:

```
function fulfill() public {
      address seaportContract = 0x00000000006c3852cbEf3e08E8dF289169EdE581;
      emit DataOrder(dataOrder);
      (bool success, bytes memory result) = seaportContract.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("fulfillBasicOrder(address,uint256,uint256,address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint8,uint256,uint256,bytes32,uint256,bytes32,bytes32,uint256,tuple[],bytes)", dataOrder));
      require(success, "call to Seaport contract failed");
  }
```

The dataOrder is: 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

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `dataOrder` already includes the function selector.

The selector is a 4-bytes element at the start of calldata with the information of the function to call. `dataOrder`'s selector is `0xfb0f3ee1` which should be the right one for `fulfillBasicOrder`.

When using `abi.encodeWithSignature(...)` you add an additional selector, which messes things up.

Basically try the following:

```
      (bool success, bytes memory result) = seaportContract.call(dataOrder);
```

Comment: Ive tried it and I still have a failed transaction :/ https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x4f03591e7686d7b465b0c7d2fc4dcad3a9f960f2e1c2016a9bd633af6185f185 , the problem is that its hard to see whats going on as there a not much informations, do you think you might help me on Discord, Ive sent you a request :)

Comment: Now you're sending only the selector. Use all the dataOrder you posted in your question

Comment: @MM1 if you are using hardhat you might try installing `hardhat-tracer` and do a `--fulltrace` on your call. it will show you how all the `call()`s are executed. If you don't have hardhat then use debug.traceTransaction() , but it will be a little bit harder to process the results